# Seeking CMIP5 or CMIP6 globally in .nc format

Tags: climate-change, models, atmosphere-modelling

Is there in some ftp storage, a pre-processing CMIP5 data for direct download in netcdf extention?

Comment: Do you know about the [Earth System Grid Federation](https://esgf-node.llnl.gov)?

Comment: thanks @Deditos ! But I can't find a direct download link in there

Comment: You won't - ESGF searches generate shell scripts that use wget to download netCDF files from the various data nodes.  There have been ad hoc ftp servers in the past, but in my experience they would come and go unreliably and weren't worth using.

Comment: it is a very good source,indeed, many thanks!! @Deditos